# NLog throws an error when loading an XmlLayout configuration file

Tags: nlog

I am attempting to configure NLog to output error logs in an XML format, however, NLog is not properly loading the configuration.

Here is the LAYOUT portion of my configuration:

```
<layout xsi:type="XmlLayout" includeAllProperties="true" propertiesElementKeyAttribute="" propertiesElementName="{0}" elementName="errorlog">
            <attribute name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
            <attribute name="level" layout="${level:upperCase=true}" />
            <element name="processname" value="${processname}" />
            <element name="logger" value="${logger}" />
            <element name="message" value="${message}" />               
        </layout>
```

When calling the LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger() method, the following error is generated:

> Parameter name not supported on XmlLayout

Here are the additional details captured in the NLog error log file:

```
    2019-03-04 16:25:39.9645 Trace   Scanning Property Renderers 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[NLog.LayoutRenderers.LayoutRenderer]' System.Collections.ObjectModel
2019-03-04 16:25:39.9645 Trace   Scanning LevelLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${level}'
2019-03-04 16:25:39.9645 Debug Setting 'XmlLayout.name' to 'processname'
2019-03-04 16:25:39.9835 Warn Error when setting 'processname' on attibute 'name' Exception: System.NotSupportedException: Parameter name not supported on XmlLayout
   at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.SetPropertyFromString(Object obj, String propertyName, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory)
   at NLog.Config.LoggingConfigurationParser.ConfigureObjectFromAttributes(Object targetObject, ILoggingConfigurationElement element, Boolean ignoreType)
2019-03-04 16:25:39.9835 Error Parsing configuration from C:\Users\<user>\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\TestingNlog\TestingNlog\bin\Debug\NLog.config failed. Exception: NLog.NLogConfigurationException: Exception when parsing C:\Users\<user>\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\TestingNlog\TestingNlog\bin\Debug\NLog.config.  ---> System.NotSupportedException: Parameter name not supported on XmlLayout
```

If I remove the ELEMENT tags from the configuration file, I am able to generate a partial log file with just the single XML element ERRORLOG with the 2 specified attributes.  However, I have not found a way to include the ELEMENT tags in my output log files.

> NLog.dll - v4.6.0.9068
>
> C# .NET - v4.7.2

Any ideas or assistance would be greatly appreciated!

-Kasey911

Comment: You are waiting for NLog 4.6.0-rc2 to be released that makes some improvements to the config-names. This is the 4.6.0-rc1 revision: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/XmlLayout/fd1b9884a3b6e9993c81079136556a2de320c8a4 (Notice `elementName` and `elementValue`)

Answer (score 1):

Snakefoot is correct,

this has been changed after NLog 4.6 RC 1

In NLog 4.6 RC 1

```xml
<layout xsi:type="XmlLayout" elementName='logevent'>
        <attribute name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
        <attribute name="level" layout="${level:upperCase=true}"/>
        <element elementName="message" elementValue="${message}" />
</layout>
```

In NLog 4.6 RC 2 (not released yet), and probably RTM

```xml
<layout xsi:type="XmlLayout" elementName='logevent'>
        <attribute name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
        <attribute name="level" layout="${level:upperCase=true}"/>
        <element name="message" value="${message}" />
</layout>
```